# fail to connect signalR hub from javascript client

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, signalr

i am trying to connect to a signalr hub which is in another domain from javascript client.

my references in the page

```
`<script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://domain/SignalR/Hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var myHub = $.connection.newHub;

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();

        // Declare a function on the blog hub so the server can invoke it
        myHub.client.BroadcastMessage= function ( message) {
            alert(message);
        };
        myHub.server.SentInfo(" message");
}
```

but the client fails to connect to hub.

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

fails and in console if i try to invoke `myHub.server.SentInfo(" message");`
it gives error as

```
Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
```

What am i missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you need to have `$.connection.hub.url = 'yourURL';` before naming your Hub variable (`var myHub = $.connection.newHub;`). You might have to play with the URL a little bit depending on how you have your Startup.cs file and CORS configured.

Comment: I added the url $.connection.hub.url , when i call $.connection.hub.start().done(){} not working  and in console $.connection.hub.state always is 0.

Comment: How do you have your Owin Startup file configured?

Comment: dont have access to server code. jst need to take care of client side. whether this is fine for client side?

Comment: If `$.connection.hub.url = "http://domain/SignalR/Hubs";` or `$.connection.hub.url ="http://domain/SignalR";` doesn't work, then I'm not too sure. Hopefully someone else can jump in and help further.

Answer (score 0):

A signalR connection does not open instantly. You need to wait until the open connection promise is fulfilled. Try the following code

```
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // Declare a function on the blog hub so the server can invoke it
        myHub.client.BroadcastMessage= function ( message) {
           alert(message);
        };

        myHub.server.SentInfo(" message");
    });
```